# Планировщик задач в vestacp

Tags: планировщик-задач

Здравствуйте собственно вопрос, установил панель управления vestacp и напоролся на проблемы с крон задачами, цель такова - нужно создать крон задачу с командой выполнения через интерпретатор пхп 5.6, создаю так:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/ЛОГИН/web/ДОМЕН/public_html/cron.php
```

срабатывает но через php 7, а мне нужно через 5.6, хостинг провайдер молчит, на оф сайте разработчиков панели в документации вообще нет ни слова о настройки и работы с планировщиком, в нете ничего не нашел кроме примера который я выше указал, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем решение такое:

```
/usr/bin/php5.6 ~/web/ДОМЕН/public_html/cron.php
```

крон заработал с интерпретатора 5.6, обращаем внимание что в адресе к файлу я убрал `/home/ЛОГИН/` так как `~/` и так подставляет эти директории. Всем спасибо.

Comment: Еще очень важно в файле крона после <? должен обязательно стоять PHP прям как в пхп 4.* почему так не известно, ведь версии начиная с 5, достаточно <?, но должно.